# Cloning more than one image javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, slideshow

I'm trying to use this glitch effect in a slideshow, so it can work I have to clone the source image 3 more times. The first image works just fine, it's when I try to add the second image of the slideshow that the problem comes up. Instead of cloning que second image itself, the first image kind of reads that like one of it's clone.
**Here's a fiddle of what I got so far https://jsfiddle.net/oqbf6kkc/**

I think the main problem is the javascript but I can't really understand.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".glitch-image img").clone().appendTo(".glitch-image").end()
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the effect you are going for, but could be that you just have an extra comma on line 337.

Comment: @Sébastien removed the comma and it's still the same. I want a glitch effect in every picture. To get that glitch effect I need to clone the image 4 times, but that I could successfully do. The thing is that when I clone the second image, the first image reads it as one of it's clones.

Comment: Do you have an example of the effect working somewhere? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trailing commas are always a problem.

[image]

Please remove the comma present in front of nth-child selector

```
.glitch-image img:nth-child(2),  {
```

Also, I am not sure about the effect you mentioned but there is some problem with your JS code as well. You are not iterating over all of the elements.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".glitch-image img").clone().appendTo(".glitch-image").end()
})
```

I made some changes to your code.
Check them [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/qkvdubq1/)

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed. I knew something was off with the js but I couldn't figure out what it was.